# Break a comprehension

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension, control-flow

Is there a way to interrupt a comprehension?

I'm thinking to something like Python's `for`-`break`-`else`.
For instance, suppose I'm traversing a list of integers, and that while I'm generating a new list out of it, I want to check that it does not contain `0`.

Can I do something like this:

```
for x <- [1, 2, 0, 3] do
    case x do
        0 -> break
        _ -> x
    end
end
if broke do
    :error
else
    :ok
end
```

I guess I'm thinking too imperative, and that the correct functional approach would be something like this, with a recursion and an accumulator:

```
def traverse_and_check(list, acc \\ []) do
    case list do
        [] -> {:ok, reverse(acc)}
        [0 | _tail] -> :error
        [x | tail] -> traverse_and_check(tail, [x | acc])
    end
end
```

Does Elixir have such a flow of control?

Comment: The only function I can think of is `Enum.reduce_while` but IMO it'll be less elegant than your recursive solution. I'd convert the `case` into 3 clauses in the declaration of `traverse_and_check/2` though.

Comment: @Dogbert Ah, you're right, I'm still fairly new to Elixir. I too find the recursive approache more elegant, but coming from Python world, the `for`-`else` appeared to me as the elegant approach at first... Although it seems to go against Elixir's philosophy that errors are not a control flow (well, technically a `break` isn't an error, but it's an "exceptional case"). Still, thanks for pointing out `Enum.reduce_while`!

Comment: I'd say you're trying to make a comprehension do something it wasn't meant to do. A comprehension is intended to work on all the elements in the set which is passed to it. If you need to jump out on a bad element then either a.) filter out any possible bad elements before starting the comprehension or b.) write recursive code which is the FP way of handling looping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are not interested in returning the collected part of the list, Elixir provides [`throw`/`catch`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html#throws) exactly for that purpose:

> In Elixir, a value can be thrown and later be caught. `throw` and `catch` are reserved for situations where it is not possible to retrieve a value unless by using `throw` and `catch`.
>
> Those situations are quite uncommon in practice except when interfacing with libraries that do not provide a proper API.

I would consider this situation being the perfect example of *“libraries [here—Elixir] that do not provide a proper API”* :)

So here you go:

```rb
try do
  for x <- [1, 2, 0, 3],
    do: if x == 0, do: throw(:break), else: x
catch
  :break -> :broken
end
#⇒ :broken
```

Please note, `throw`/`catch` are intended to control the flow, unlike `raise`/`rescue`.

Comment: I'd use this. I absolutely didn't even think about using throw/catch here!

Comment: @Dogbert I am not sure; with `reduce_while` one might fake the ruby’s `break acc` functionality, returning the _already collected elements_. `throw`ing from a comprehension has no access to an accumulator.

Comment: yep, but if OP doesn't want the partial list, this is a nice way to break.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I was looking for. I just came up with the same solution, but with `raise`. Of course, `throw`/`catch` is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enum.reduce_while/3` but the solution is worse than recursion in my opinion since it requires a `case` afterwords to reduce the list for the non breaking case. The snippet below includes the `reduce_while` implementation and an improved recursive solution based on your code:

```
defmodule A do
  def f(list) do
    Enum.reduce_while(list, [], fn x, acc ->
      if x == 0, do: {:halt, :break}, else: {:cont, [x | acc]}
    end)
    |> case do
      :break -> :break
      list -> Enum.reverse(list)
    end
  end

  def g(list, acc \\ [])

  def g([], acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc)
  def g([0 | _], _), do: :break
  def g([x | xs], acc), do: g(xs, [x | acc])
end

IO.inspect(A.f([1, 2, 3]))
IO.inspect(A.f([1, 2, 0, 3]))
IO.inspect(A.g([1, 2, 3]))
IO.inspect(A.g([1, 2, 0, 3]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
:break
[1, 2, 3]
:break
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#generators-and-filters) page of the getting-started manual.

Comprehensions have optional filters that you can use in place of the standard filter/reduce functions. Try something like this:

```
for x <- [1, 2, 0, 3], x != 0, into: [] do: x
```

The documentation has some better examples, but this should do for your use case of removing zeros from a list in a comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not *filtering certain elements out*, but *interrupting the iteration upon realization of a certain condition*, along with *capturing the breaking*.

Comment: @Rightleg, Oops, sorry, I misunderstood the question.